# AnkhSVN settings menus not showing up in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ankhsvn

I want to change the compare tool that AnkhSVN uses in VS2012 but the "Subversion Environment" and  "Subversion User Tools" menus aren't showing up like they do in VS2010.

Here's what I should see:

[image: What I should see]

But this is what I'm seeing in VS2012:

[image: Actually seeing]

This is with AnkhSVN v 2.4.11610.27 (the latest stable version as of this question being created).

I am using VS2012 Ultimate but, presumably, this problem would also occur on any VS2012 version which supports plugins.

I also have TortoiseSVN installed on my computer but I doubt that it related to this problem.

I've tried reinstalling the AnkhSVN plugin but this does not change it.  Other than this problem the AnkhSVN plugin seems to be working correctly.

I haven't been able to find any mention of this problem on the CollabNet web site.

Do you know how to get these menu items to show up?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm sure if this will work for everyone but I found that doing a complete uninstall/reinstall of AnkhSVN solved the problem for me and go into Advanced during the installation and ensure that VS2012 is selected.

I had tried a repair before this and it didn't solve the problem.  It needed to be an uninstall/reinstall with VS2012 selected in Advanced.

Answer (score 7):

This happened to me because the AnkhSVN was not my active source code control provider. See
tools->options->source control and choose AnkhSVN.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue by following steps mentioned below.

1.Uninstall/reinstall with VS2012 selected.

2.Go to the VS-> tools->options->source and select AnkhSVN for the source control plugin .