# AnkhSvn is installed but not working in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2013, ankhsvn

I have installed Visual studio 2013 , and I have installed AnkhSvn-2.5.12266.msi for svn, but this "Add-On" is not available in Visual Studio. Why?

Comment: The proper "Pending Changes" windows is also not availabe in this situation.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

It is there. Just change the source control options in visual studio to use Ankh instead of TFS.

Go to `Tools/Options/Source Control/Plug-in Selection`, select the AnkhSVN plug-in.

Then restart visual studio and you are good to go. Its working perfectly for me.

Or reinstall the complete ankhsvn client. As this guy here:

[AnkhSVN settings menus not showing up in VS2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15276020/ankhsvn-settings-menus-not-showing-up-in-vs2012)

Answer (score 23):

To add to previous answer I'd like to set up [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/downloads/) as external Diff and Merge Tools after setting the source control plug-in (you have to install WinMerge first):

Visual Studio -> TOOLS -> Options -> Expand the "Source Control" Node

[image: VS2013 AnkhSVN Plug-In Selection]

[image: VS2013 Subversion User Tools]

Double click on the Pending Changes will show the change in WinMerge:

[image]

Comment: Although my problem was solved , your answer is correct.

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to Tools/Options
2. Select Source Control/Plug-in Selection
3. Under Current source control plug-in select AnkhSVN - SubVersion Support for Visual Studio